# Generate QueryBuilder from dotted path

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm about to create a `QueryBuilder` generator based on potential dotted path fields.

Imagine 3 entities: `Site` linked to a `Customer` linked to an `Address`

I need to get the city of the address of the customer of a given site:

> site.customer.address.city

would generate this query:

```
$qb = $em->getRepository(Site::class)->createQueryBuilder()
$qb
    ->select('address.city')
    ->join('customer', 'customer')
    ->join('customer.address', 'address')
;
```

I'm thinking to make a recursive function to just generate the pairs `join` => `alias` array

Are there some tools I can use to not reinvent the wheel ?

Otherwise I'll answer with my solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my dump solution

```
/**
 * @param string|array $dottedParts
 * @param string $parent
 * @return array
 */
public function getJoinsFromDottedPath($dottedParts, $parent = 'entity')
{
    if (!is_array($dottedParts)) {
        // Assuming the $dottedParts is a string
        if (!strstr($dottedParts, '.')) {
            // Exiting if this string does not contain any dot
            return array();
        }
        // Converting into array
        $dottedParts = explode('.', $dottedParts);
    }
    $joins = array();
    // Adding the current join
    $joins[$parent.'.'.$dottedParts[0]] = $dottedParts[0];
    if (count($dottedParts) > 2) {
        // There are children
        $parent = array_shift($dottedParts);
        $children = $this->getJoinsFromDottedPath($dottedParts, $parent);
        // They are part of the family
        $joins = array_merge($joins, $children);
    }

    return $joins;
}
```

With his test

```
function testGetJoinsFromDottedPath()
{
    $joins = $this->admin->getJoinsFromDottedPath('site.customer');
    $this->assertCount(1, $joins);
    $this->assertEquals('entity.site', array_keys($joins)[0]);
    $this->assertEquals('site', array_values($joins)[0]);

    $joins = $this->admin->getJoinsFromDottedPath('site.customer.address.city');
    $this->assertCount(3, $joins);
    $this->assertEquals('entity.site', array_keys($joins)[0]);
    $this->assertEquals('site', array_values($joins)[0]);
    $this->assertEquals('site.customer', array_keys($joins)[1]);
    $this->assertEquals('customer', array_values($joins)[1]);
    $this->assertEquals('customer.address', array_keys($joins)[2]);
    $this->assertEquals('address', array_values($joins)[2]);
}
```

Feel free to improve the related [gist](https://gist.github.com/Glideh/0d4f09bede787190de88c67d3e370323) and/or suggest any better solution